# For loop with steps OPL Cplex

Tags: for-loop, matrix, cplex

I need to write matrices of different dimensions in *OPL CPLEX*.

Currently, I wrote this for loop :

```
{int} row=...;
{int} col=...;
int y[row][col];

execute
{
 for (var i=1; i<=row.size; i+=10){
   for (var j in col){
     y[i][j]=i;
   }
 }
 writeln("y= ",y, 
 "/ row = ", row.size,
 "/ col = ", col.size,
 "/ time = ", cplex.getCplexTime());
}
```

Currently, in the scripting log, I obtain as a solution all the matrices (from `1x2` to `100x2`).

I would like to compute (and print) only the matrices `1x2`, `10x2`, `20x2`, ..., `90x2` and `100x2`.

Essentially I would like to print a matrix every `10` rows (so in total `11` matrices and not `100`).

I tried to multiply the row.size per `10` (or divide it per `10` when the row value is `100`).

How can I do that ?

---

### UPDATE :

**`main.mod`** :

```
{int} set1={};
{int} set2={};
int ar[1..100][1..100];

main { 
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");  
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
  for(var i=1;i<=30;i++) if (i % 10 == 0) { 
    for (var j=1; j<=30; j++) if (j % 10 == 0) {
        var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);  
        var data2= new IloOplDataElements(); 
        data2.row=thisOplModel.set1; 
        data2.row.add(i); 
        data2.col=thisOplModel.set2; 
        data2.col.add(j);
    } 
  opl.addDataSource(data2); 
  opl.generate(); 
}
if (cplex.solve()) {  
writeln("Solution = " + cplex.getObjValue(),
"/ time = ", cplex.getCplexTime());
} else {
    writeln("No solution");
}
data2.end(); 
opl.end();
}
```

**`sub.mod` :**

```
{int} row=...;
{int} col=...;
int y[row][col];


execute {
 
 for (var i in row) {
     for (var j in col) { 
        y[i][j]=i; 
    } 
 } 
    writeln("y= ",y, 
//    " / i= ", i,
//  "/ row = ", row,
    "/ col = ", col,
    "/ time = ", cplex.getCplexTime());
}

dvar float x;

maximize x;
subject to {
   x<=sum(i in row, j in col) y[i][j];
}

execute
{
writeln("x=",x);
}
```

Now, I obtain the right values in `row = {10, 20, 30}` and `col = {10, 20, 30}` in the `main.mod`.

In `sub.mod` row and col are sets. I need to use those values as matrices dimensions. So the first matrix is `10x10`, the second `20x20` etc..

How can I access the values inside the set so that I can create those matrices ?

Sorry for the multiple questions but I am really new to *CPLEX*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use modulo

```
range r=1..100;

execute
{
  for(var i in r) if (i % 10==0) writeln(i);
}
```

gives

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your answer. I have updated the question better specifying my problem. Essentially the values you have found should become the dimensions of my matrices, but I don't know how to access those values and make them the new matrices dimensions

Comment: Have you had a look at asSet . This can turn 1..5 into a set with 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly rewrite your `sub.mod` to get this going:

```
{int} rowSet = ...;
{int} colSet = ...;

range row = 1..last(rowSet);
range col = 1..last(colSet);

int y[row][col];

execute {
  for (var i in row) {
    for (var j in col) {
      y[i][j] = i;
    }
  }
  writeln(y);
}
```

The `last` function will return the last element from the respective set. So in the first iteration you get 10, in the second 20 and in the third 30. Then `row` and `col` are constructed as range with the desired number of elements. These can then be used to initialize the array.

Note that in `main.mod` you must replace `data2.row` by `data2.rowSet` and `data2.col` by `data2.colSet`.